# Use sqlcmd in batch to process collection of .sql files

Tags: sql, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have a collection of .sql files in the directory `C:\Files`

The .sql files are generated continuously throughout the day.

The files follow the naming logic `TRANS[i].sql`

Each file contains SQL code to be executed via sqlcmd. Once the code of a file has been executed successfully, the file should be moved to `C:\Files\Old`

How do I write a batch file which will process all .sql files and move them to the designated folder?

This is a sample of the batch I currently have, which can execute the code of only a single .sql file, and cannot move it subsequently:

```
    sqlcmd -S SERVER01 -i C:\Files\TRANS1.sql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was easier than I anticipated:

```
for %%f in (.\*sql) do sqlcmd -S SERVER01 -i %%f & move "%%f" .\Old
```